# Bullet lists in the experience blurb don't show up in the public CV

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

If you specify your responsibilities as a bullet list it doesn't show up on the public CV view even if the live preview renders the bullets correctly.

EDIT: Cool! Can I get a red tag too? :)

Here's some screenshots; It may very well be just me...

[screenshot - published http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/9349/careersbug1.png](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/9349/careersbug1.png)
[screenshot - edit preview http://img175.imageshack.us/img175/3959/careersbug2.png](http://img175.imageshack.us/img175/3959/careersbug2.png)
[screenshot - bullet mode http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/7760/careersbug3.png](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/7760/careersbug3.png)

Comment: I don't think you have this field checked in the publish preferences... does it show up in the private CV view? If so, then your privacy settings prohibit it from showing in the public CV.

Answer (score 1):

I can't repro this.

I entered the following text for responsibilities:

```
- bullet 1
- bullet 2
- bullet 3
```

And I got this on the public cv view:

http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/1281/image3i.png

Comment: What a wonderful set of skills. Just what we are looking for. Can I make you a job offer? ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I edited my question with screenshots showing that here it's still happening...